# How to properly use a composite key using SQL code in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, select

So I am making a small software for a Hotel Management System and I need some help calling the values from the database. In my database I have a table called KOT. This table has the following columns: idfood , iditem , amount. 'idfood' and 'iditem' are both primary keys forming a composite key.

This is what the database looks like with test values (I'm sorry I had to use an image hosting site, I don't have enough reputation to post on this site):
http://oi61.tinypic.com/3468eb8.jpg

Now I made an interface in NetBeans which looks like this:
http://oi61.tinypic.com/x5sj2e.jpg

What I want to happen is, when I enter a value in the text box (For example '1') all the records which have idfood as '1' should display in the table. I would appreciate any help.

Following is my code (the button named 'Search'):

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

    String a = jTextField1.getText();

    try {

        Statement s = DB.getConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM keys WHERE idfood = '"+a+"'");

        while(rs.next()){

            Vector v = new Vector();
            v.add(rs.getString("idfood"));
            v.add(rs.getString("iditem"));
            v.add(rs.getString("amount"));

            dtm.addRow(v);
        }
    } 

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Just a side note: use `PreparedStatement` instead of manually adding the parameters to the query. `" ... idfood = '" + a + "'"` is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: use [PreparedStatements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) rather than passing like this `+a+` since its highly vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: Btw, what's your question? Do you have problems running your code?

Comment: When I run the above code, I get this error: "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'keys WHERE idfood = '1'' at line 1"

Comment: We'll need the table schema.

Comment: @chrylis this is what the table looks like: http://oi61.tinypic.com/3468eb8.jpg

Comment: Post code, not links to images.

Comment: @chrylis Codes of what? The table? I don't have the code for the table because SQL Query Browser made the table for me. This is what the table design stage looked like: http://oi61.tinypic.com/2znpwgh.jpg